# Trying to add sample size to each row label in a dataframe

Tags: r

I am creating a final dataframe that has a list of different coral species. I have the dataframe set up the way I want it. All I want to do is add the sample size of each coral species to the row labels (i.e. final label will look like this example: Acropora sp. (plating) n=10). 
I have a list of all coral species with their sample size but I am not sure how to incorporate that data into the row labels.

````
count_focal_taxa = tapply(FR3_final$Type,FR3_final$Type,length)
count_focal_taxa
``

     Acropora_sp_plating            Corallimorph        Favia_stelligera 
                     10                      12                      84 
 My dataframe is currently:

`

    ``{r}
    result <- data.frame(ifelse(FR3_final_means > quantile_high, '+', ifelse(FR3_final_means < quantile_low, '-', 0)))
    result$Type<-(FR3_final_means$Type)
    result
    ```

        Type                A   B   C   D   E   F   G
        Acropora_sp_plating 0   0   0   0   +   0   0   
        Corallimorph        +   0   0   0   0   0   0   
        Favia_stelligera    0   0   0   0   0   -   +

And I want:

    Type                        A   B   C   D   E   F   G
    Acropora_sp_plating n=10    0   0   0   0   +   0   0   
    Corallimorph n=12           +   0   0   0   0   0   0   
    Favia_stelligera n=84       0   0   0   0   0   -   +
````

Comment: Sorry I just added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `paste`

```
result$Type = paste(result$Type, 'n=', count_focal_taxa)
```

Or with `sprintf`

```
result$Type <- sprintf('%s n=%d', result$Type, count_focal_taxa)
```

---

Instead of `tapply`, we can get the frequency with `table`

```
count_focal_taxa <- table(FR3_final$Type)
```

Comment: Akrun, how on earth are you so quick to answer these questions. My God!

Comment: care to share what resources you use when tackling all the questions you take on? If I were to guess, you pull all your syntax and explanations out of memory, but maybe not... maybe you are...human?

Comment: Thank you so much!